Adding google's in-app update feature in my App
I wanted to add google's in-app feature in my app. Firstly I added the following dependencies in my gradle file:

implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'


Next I the checked the availability of an update using the following code block:
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(getApplicationContext());

    // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
    Task<AppUpdateInfo> appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.getAppUpdateInfo();

    // Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
    appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener(appUpdateInfo -> {
        if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
                // This example applies an immediate update. To apply a flexible update
                // instead, pass in AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
                && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)){
                }
            });

Next I started an app update using the following code in the if statement above:
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
// Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
appUpdateInfo,
// an activity result launcher registered via registerForActivityResult
activityResultLauncher,
// Or pass 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' to newBuilder() for
// flexible updates.
AppUpdateOptions.newBuilder(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE).build());
Initially the following error was showing up for activityResult Launcher:
enter image description here
To fix this I used the following solution:
enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
Next I made sure that the version code of my newer version of my app(the one I'm working on) is less than the version code of my app available on the playstore.
However, despite following the steps mentioned above the in-app update feature is still not working. Initially it was working fine but then out of nowhere it stopped working. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way tried to handle the activityResultLauncher
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks
However, despite following the steps mentioned above the in-app update feature is still not working. Initially it was working fine but then out of nowhere it stopped working. I have a feeling it has something to do with the way tried to handle the activityResultLauncher
